# Datasheet View Resizing

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Form - DatasheetView, that constantly shows execessive columns (no field/data) and i would like to resize the view port of the form to include only the fields shown.

Currently, i have all the fields on the form being Resized as Bestfit (`ColumnWidth = -2`) and not sure if that is what is causing the excessive columns to be shown.

How do i set the width of the datasheet view-port to be only the columns included?  As well, is there a way to turn off the left spacer column?

This form will be for data-entry and editing

Comment: What is the record source? Have you considered a continuous form?

Comment: The end-user wants it to look like Excel with the row/columns.  I am trying to remove them from using Excel as a database.  I tried doing the record navigation style form but the end-user didnt want to have to click through all the records (even with the Search component).

Comment: A continuous form can look like Excel. You can capture input and provide navigation. What is the record source?

Comment: You have set the record source to the name of a table. Is that correct? Set it to an SQL string that only includes the fields (columns) that you need.

Comment: Pretty much all the fields, outside of the control-field, are editable.  So all fields are required.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15582/discussion-between-remou-and-goldbishop)

Comment: Thanx for the point in the right direction.  Having a couple more problems with other forms, with this new found (for me) layout ;)

Comment: You can either use a query or set up the combo in a different way. It depends on where your updates are done.